# Failed to fetch index files when tried apt-get update

Tags: apt, partitioning, updates

I recently have installed an Ubuntu operating system and now I have a lot of problems getting it to work.

First of all, I have not partitioned it when booting, and now I need to partition the HDD, but I think a program is needed so I have tried to get gparted.
When I try to update my repository it shows some errors on the screen such as

> some index files failed to download

or

> 404 package not found

I really don't know what to do with it. I am new to this operating system so I don't understand technical phrases.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually not fatal .. as the error message says '**Some**' Index files failed to download. Follows the same with 404 package error. you can either ignore this or update repositories and PPAs.

```
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/main Translation-en             
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/multiverse Translation-en       
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/restricted Translation-en       
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/universe Translation-en         
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/main Sources                  
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/universe Sources              
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/main i386 Packages            
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/universe i386 Packages        
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/main Translation-en           
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/universe Translation-en       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid/main i386 Packages                          
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid/main Translation-en [154 B]                 
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid/main i386 Packages                          
404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid/main Translation-en_IN                      
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid/main Translation-en                         
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid/main i386 Packages                          
404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid/main Translation-en_IN                      
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid/main Translation-en                         
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid/main i386 Packages                          
404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid/main Translation-en_IN                      
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid/main Translation-en                         
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid/main i386 Packages                          
404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid/main Translation-en_IN                      
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid/main Translation-en                         
Fetched 59.6 kB in 29s (1,987 B/s)                                             
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ackondro/tibesti/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/office/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/vokoscreen-dev/vokoscreen/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

The above are the last few lines ,when i run apt-get update in my system. 
You need not worry unless it is causing troubles in particular issues (ex:installing some new applications , some file operations etc)

But if you want to be safe then you can try updating your repository source links. This is usually caused if you have outdated sources as your ubuntu repository links. So, updating repositories will solve this error.

Go through [This](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine) for additional information about Ubuntu repositories.

Follow [This](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) link if you want to update repositories and PPAs for your version of ubuntu.

You can even update them by your Ubuntu update manager. [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories) --follow this link to know how.